# How would you create new elements based on an ajax query after initial load in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dynamic, reactjs

I am new to using React.js.  In theory, it looks pretty neat, but I'm having to rethink how I would solve even simple problems that I am used to solving with jQuery.  One of those is how to generate components dynamically after an initial load based on user input.

Let's say that I have a `<SearchBox />`, and I want the user to be able to enter a query, click search, and generate an arbitrary number of `<SearchResult />` components, based upon the results of an ajax call.  I would assume I would create an update method attached to the SearchBox that would be called onClick to grab the data, but how would I go about dynamically rendering the SearchResult components after each search once the data arrives?

I suppose I am looking for something along the lines of Angular's `ng-repeat` directive, but I'm not seeing anything to that effect in React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong but I think it could be as simple as:

```
...
render: function() {
  var length = data.length; // data contains the result you received from AJAX
  var searchResultObjects = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
    searchResultObjects[searchResultObjects.length] = <SearchResult />;
  }
  return (
    <ul>
      {searchResultObjects} // assuming that your SearchResult object returns an <li> item from its render function 
    </ul>
  );
}
...
```

And **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/69z2wepo/11999/)** is an example of just that.

***Update:***

Take a look at this **[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/69z2wepo/12004/)** with the example of updating the results and observe the events in the `console` window of the Developer Tools of your browser. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Hm.  That looks pretty close to what I'm after.  I wonder though, if the user does multiple queries and the UL contents are overwritten multiple times, are there going to be artifacts from prior search results that slow the system down?  Do you know of prior components have to be de-registered somehow before the update?

Comment: You either overwrite the `<ul>` over and over again or you keep pushing the objects into the array, in both the cases, I think `SearchBox` object keeps calling its `render` method and view gets updated on its own. React finds the differences in HTML on its own internally, and does a fine job re-rendering if need be. I don't think there is any performance disadvantage here.

Comment: When a `SearchResult` gets un-mounted from the view in the case of over-writing the `<ul>` with new `SearchResult` objects, the internal [`componentWillUnmount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#unmounting-componentwillunmount) callback is triggered which you can use to clean-up any given `SearchResult` object internal stuff.

Comment: @meesterguyperson: added an **Update** above.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make a list is to map the search results to a React component and add the data to a prop.

```
render: function() {
    var searchResultItems = this.state.searchResults.map(function(object, index) {
        return <SearchResult key={index} data={object} /> // Mapping each item to a React component with the results in a data prop 
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <SearchBox />
            <ul>
                {searchResultItems}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Make sure to always add a key so React can easily differentiate each item.
You could keep the search results in the state and use setState to update it after a new search, it will rerender that way.